# How to detect file path in a string of html codes

Tags: html, detect, filepath

I need to read in a string of HTML codes using ajax and refactor every file path found in the string.

For example:

I need to detect "../../images/home.jpg" 
And change it to "http://www.mywebsite.com/report/images/home.jpg".

I am actually doing a dashboard. Using iframe to display content in a dashboard cost me performance. In order to not use iframe, I intend to read in the string of html codes of the targeted URL. But the only factor here is that if the filepath of any images, javascript or css are not absolute path, my dashboard will not be able to display.

Please give your thoughts in how you would detect file path within a string of html codes or is there any existing library that you know of.

Here is one of a simple html codes i am reading from.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1"><title>
    Web Report: Customer Complains
</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/Concept1.css" /></head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<body>
        <div class="SectionTitleContainer1">
            <div style="text-align: left;" class="SectionTitle">
                Customer Complaints
            </div>
        </div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="width: 100%;" border="0">

        <tr>
            <td width="1%" align="left">
                <a>
                Refund 

                    </a>
            </td>
            <td width="1%" style="text-align: right">139</td>
            <td align="left" style="">
                <img src="../../../images/tile-horiz-bar.png" style="height: 10px; width: 100px" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="1%" align="left">
                <a>
                Appointment Rescheduled/Delayed 

                    </a>
            </td>
            <td width="1%" style="text-align: right">96</td>
            <td align="left" style="">
                <img src="../../../images/tile-horiz-bar.png" style="height: 10px; width: 69px" />
            </td>
        </tr>                
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a complete example of your input html fragment. If it is well formed, you could use xslt to solve this.

Comment: The html codes that is read is not fixed. Therefore I have to detect keyword such as "src" for javascript and "url('')" for css. But before going ahead to code them, would like to hear from more people. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long period of discovery, I learned that if there is a need for two different system to display identical UI, we should place the image files (or any other script files) in a common directory within a server. Web app should be given proper permission to access the files in the local directory of the server. The directory holding the image files should not be secured and not exposing to the public (if necessary).